Unable to Access Node.js Application on Internet deployed under SAP BTP Kyma Environment
I have deployed a Node.js application in the SAP BTP Kyma environment. I have enabled Istio sidecar injection in my namespace and created an API Rule to expose my service to the internet. However, I am unable to access my application.
Here are the steps i have followed:

I Enabled Istio Sidecar Injection: "kubectl label namespaces istio-injection=enabled"

I Created API Rule:




Service Configuration:


Issues:
1.Tried to verify the istio injection using the following command, "istioctl experimental check-inject -n   "
I got the following response that "The injection webhook is deactivated, and will never match labels":

Questions:

Is there anything I am missing or doing incorrectly in the setup?
How can I troubleshoot why the sidecar injection might not be working correctly?
Are there additional steps required to expose my application to the internet in the Kyma environment?

Any help?
